# How to write windows script to dial a connection

Tags: windows-7, ppp

Is it possible to dial-up and hang-up a connection? The connection is a PPP 3G connection in my Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of Windows, I used the command Rasdial. It appears to still be present in Windows 7.

```
c:> Rasdial "My PPP Connection"
```

To disconnect

```
c:> Rasdial "My PPP Connection" /disconnect
```

If you want more control, you can use your favorite scripting language to exercise the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377004%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Good one there. Out of curiosity, is it `c:\>` or `c:>` on Win 7?

Comment: Well, you could configure your prompt to display whatever you want. I just wanted some indicator that it was running from a DOS-like shell. `c:\>` is probably more common.